# move label laterally with timer and button

Tags: java, netbeans, label

I'm using Netbeans to try and create a little minigame for a class project. We haven't learned to make objects move, and I want to do a little extra.

Consider that I have a label and a button. When I click the button, I want the label to begin moving laterally to the right, parallel to the x-axis. How do I do this?

Comment: are using swing libraries for this?

Comment: Check out java-gaming.org as an excellent resource for questions related to games and Java. I'm not clear that the answer for Hovercraft's "duplicate" is the best, actually. Also, there are better ways to do animation that using buttons and labels. It would be easier to answer at JGO.